# Deploy php project with POST form on Google Cloud run

Tags: php, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I would like to deploy my php project to Google cloud run.

My goal is to have one `index.php` which shows some information and a `Download CSV` form (submit).
When user click the `Download CSV`, there would be a `POST` request and goes to `csv_download.php` to perform the download.

`index.php` looks like:

```
// some html

<?php
echo '<form name="getcsv" method="POST" action="csv_download.php">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Download csv" />'
echo '</form>';
?>

// some html
```

`csv_download.php` looks like:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
// some code to deal with csv
fclose($fp);
?>
```

And the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" opcache
RUN set -ex; \
    { \
    echo "; Cloud Run enforces memory & timeouts"; \
    echo "memory_limit = -1"; \
    echo "max_execution_time = 0"; \
    echo "; File upload at Cloud Run network limit"; \
    echo "upload_max_filesize = 32M"; \
    echo "post_max_size = 32M"; \
    echo "; Configure Opcache for Containers"; \
    echo "opcache.enable = On"; \
    echo "opcache.validate_timestamps = Off"; \
    echo "; Configure Opcache Memory (Application-specific)"; \
    echo "opcache.memory_consumption = 32"; \
    } > "$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/cloud-run.ini"

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . ./

RUN sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

All three files are stored in the same directory.

Everything works fine when testing on localhost, when the user click the `Download CSV` form, `test.csv` will be downloaded.
But when I run the project on Google gcp cloud run, `csv_download.php` is not working properly.
The file being downloaded is not `test.csv`, but a file named `csv_download.php` with target csv content inside.

I've tried deploying and running only the `csv_download.php` on cloud run, it worked (the `test.csv` is downloaded).
So I am wondering if my `Dockerfile` is the problem?

Comment: I tried to replicate your three files then deployed it on Google Cloud Run and it worked the file being downloaded is `test.csv`. Could you please try again to re-deploy using this command `gcloud run deploy [service name] --source=[souce], based on this documentation[https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code#deploying].

Comment: @SarahRemo Thanks a lot! I figured out why my code was not working. Neither the `php` code nor the `Dockerfile` is problematic, it is because my filename in my original code is in Chinese, which causes a encoding problem (Big5 to UTF-8).

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so that other members of the community who have similar or related problem can get your help.

Answer (score 2):

As per @MinaCheng, Neither the php code nor the Dockerfile is problematic, it is because my filename in my original code is in Chinese, which causes an encoding problem (Big5 to UTF-8).